# Await client async

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have some code that's bugging me due to my lack of knowledge on Async in c#.

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(string apiURL)
    {
        _client = await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask;

        var response = await _client.GetAsync(apiURL);

        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            //todo: check
            return responseContent.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        } 
    }
```

My question is i want to get the content from the response, in my example i await the response so i can obtain the content.

However should i use await to get the content, if not then how do i get the content from the response if i don't await.

Comment: As a general rule, If you are receiving a `Task`, you should `await` it (if you can)

Comment: I agree with  @MatiasCicero, and I personally would do `return await responseContent;` instead.

Comment: ah my lead is suggesting i refactor my code and don't bother with awaits... gave no reason as to why but i questioned my code.  I do wonder though, this result gets fired but my controller doesn't get notified (no need to) instead theirs a logging section that checks all this separate, in that case i shouldn't await at all?

Comment: Note that using `await` means that you don't block a thread.  If you use `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` you block the thread.  That's the main (but not only) difference and it would mostly effect performance when under load.

Comment: With responseContent.Result you block the thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)